# Generalized words

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

Dan Segal, in his book 'Words', has defined generalized words. I have trouble understanding generalized words. What I have understood from the definition of generalized words are as follows:
Let $X = \{x_1, \ldots,x_n \}$ and $\Phi = \{ \phi_1,\ldots,\phi_s \}$ be two sets. Consider a free group $F(X^{\Phi})$ on the set $\{ x^{\phi } \vert x \in X, \phi \in \Phi \}$ as a subgroup of free group $F(X \cup \Phi)$ on the set $X \cup \Phi$. An element of $F(X^{\Phi})$ is said to be a generalized word. If we see $x^{\phi} = \phi^{-1}x\phi$, then it is clear that $F(X^{\Phi})$ is a subgroup of $F(X \cup \Phi)$. A generalised word will look like $w = \prod_{j=1}^r x_{i_j}^{\epsilon_j\phi_{k_j}}$ where $i_j \in \{ 1,\ldots n\}, \epsilon_j \in \pm1, k_j \in \{ 1,\ldots s\}$.

To define a generalised word map on any group $G$, we first associate the set $\Phi$ with a subset $\Psi = \{ \psi_1, \ldots, \psi_s \}$ of automorphisms of group $G$ such that each $\phi_i$ goes to $\psi_i$. $w(g_1,\ldots, g_n) = \prod_{j=1}^r g_{i_j}^{\epsilon_j \psi_{k_j}}$. Here $g_i^{\psi_k}$ means $\psi_k (g_i)$.

Is it correct definition?

What was the motivation to define generalized words.

And why is it important to study?

Comment: "What was the motivation": have you looked in this book where generalized are used?

Comment: It is being developed for technique to see finiteness of verbal width of words in certain groups . But I don't know how they are using it. I am also not sure that I am understanding it correctly.

Comment: I very much doubt that you will get a good answer to this question here. As @YCor says, the answers to your question are surely in Segal's book. It is normal to be confused when you first encounter a complicated definition, but further reading and attempting to use the definition (even to write out your own account of Segal's proof) will probably be more helpful than asking vague questions here. I'm going to vote to close your question now, but hopefully with a bit more study you can ask a more focussed question.